# Is there any function like StepOneFrameForward (UWP) in WPF for MediaElement.Position?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I access MediaElement1.Position after the MediaElement1 was paused and started, I get 00:00 for one second, and then it gets normal.

Like this 00:00 -> 00:01 -> 00:02 -> Pause -> Start -> 00:00 (00:03 should be shown) -> 00:04 -> 00:05 ...

I read that UWP has a function called StepOneFrameForward for that. Does WPF have it, too?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does WPF have it, too?

No, it doesn't. You can confirm this by looking in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for the `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer` class.

You may still use the UWP control in a WPF application using [XAML islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/mediaplayerelement?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).